# running .command files with applescript or xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, applescript

I was wondering if there was a way to get an applescript app to run .command files. If not can someone help me with how to do this in xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Any file that you can execute on the command line can be run from AppleScript with the `do shell script` command.

```
set homeListing to (do shell script "cd ~; source .bash_profile;")
```

Comment: can you expleain this to me a little bit better. the file i want to lauch is here /Users/Alego/Desktop/minecraft_server

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with the term ".command files," so I assumed that you were referring to a UNIX executable whose name begins with a dot (like `.bash_profile`). Is this a command line tool or a file that should be opened by a program? If the latter, will the files open properly if you double-click them in the Finder? If so, then you can use the `open` command in AppleScript, as in `tell application "Finder" to open "Macintosh HD:Users:Alego:Desktop:minecraft_server"`. If minecraft_server is an application you can use `launch` instead of `open`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just open a .command file, try this:

```
do shell script "open /path/to/myFile.command"
```